# Play short video sequences as one long video on WP7

Tags: video, windows-phone-7

I'd like to write a Windows Phone 7 app, where you can connect a lot of short video sequenzes to one seamless video for playing (I don't want to edit and really create the video, just play the short ones in a special (not quite random) order).

Is it possible to get a lot of videos on the phone and play them seamless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest piece of code to play a video on the Windows Phone 7 is -

```
// media1 is <MediaElement x:Name="media1" />
media1.Source = new Uri("http://yoursite/yourvideo.wmv");
media1.Play();
```

Since you wish to loop through a number of videos, you can add an event handler for MediaEnded event

```
media1.MediaEnded += new RoutedEventHandler(media1_MediaEnded);
```

and load the next media file within the `media1_MediaEnded` event handler. You may add a PerformanceProgressBar animation that is visible until the media is opened, you can turn off the animation in the MediaElement's MediaOpened event.

Although it is relevant for MP3 files, I found [Tim Heuer's post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/16/download-and-store-media-for-playback-in-windows-phone-7-using-mediastreamsource.aspx) very useful to design my applications. You may need to consider looking at the [list of supported media codecs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) in Windows Phone 7 as all media files may not play on the phone.

HTH, indyfromoz